# kundera vs native datastax driver

Tags: java, cassandra

I am building a REST API and I am using cassandra as my datastore. I did some research on the java driver and short listed Kundera and datastax driver. If someone has experience in using both these driver can you please let me know what are the advantage/disadvantages of these 2 drivers. The only thing I learned from my research is that Kundera is JPA compliant and treats NoSQL databases as SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I never used kundera but i read the docu. Kundera is a wrapper around the datastax driver. https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Datastax-java-driver-support-for-Cassandra-using-Kundera

You can compare them but kundera is build for another use case. It fits more to the use cases of spark. For your use case the pure datastax driver is the better option. If you need to join other sources etc. (These Ad-Hoc Analytics or Aggregation stuff) use kundera or spark or whatever.